# How to run line by line query in mysql query browser

Tags: mysql

Suppose that I want to execute two query one is-

```
select * from table1;

select * from table2;
```

if I want to execute it I need to remove one query from two then I can execute, I'm using mysql query browser1.2.12.
If we use script tab then I can not see the output, is there any way to execute one of query from multiple query after selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql Query Browser is getting old nowdays. Mysql launch the new generation IDE with name Mysql Workbench.
use it,here u got more options.
enjoy!!
[click here for workbench](http://mysql.com/downloads/workbench/#downloads)

Answer (score 0):

that functionality is not available in mysql query browser on any version.

Comment: are you sure about this? i think my friend is using mysql query browser where he can run any selected query. but he is working over windows and i m working over ubuntu 10.10